# Shell script to get list of defined users on Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk

I put this together, but it sucks: (e.g. magic numbers in there, text parsing.. boo!)

```
awk -F: '{if($3 >= 1000 && $3 < 2**16-2) print $1}' /etc/passwd
```

What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: What's wrong with text parsing?

Answer (score 13):

Some unix systems don't use `/etc/passwd`, or have users that are not specified there.  You should use `getent passwd` instead of reading `/etc/passwd`.

My system also has users that are disabled and can lo longer login with their login command set to `/bin/false` or `/usr/sbin/nologin`.  You probably want to exclude them as well.

Here is what works for me including arheops awk command and ansgar's code to get the min and max from `login.defs`:

```
getent passwd | \
grep -vE '(nologin|false)$' | \
awk -F: -v min=`awk '/^UID_MIN/ {print $2}' /etc/login.defs` \
-v max=`awk '/^UID_MAX/ {print $2}' /etc/login.defs` \
'{if(($3 >= min)&&($3 <= max)) print $1}' | \
sort -u
```

Comment: Works nicely on my home network, despite LDAP users, automounted home directories with strange paths, etc.  It does produce duplicates for users who have both LDAP and fallback /etc/passwd entries, but otherwise, nice.

Comment: Duplicates can be eliminated by appending a `| sort -u`.

Comment: ... or by using a temporary array as part of the `awk` command.

Answer (score 2):

I am unsure why you do only > 1000, beacuase on redhat system it start from 500.

For me this awk script work ok:

```
awk -F: '{if(($3 >= 500)&&($3 <65534)) print $1}' /etc/passwd
```

Only uses with passwords:

```
awk -F: '{if(!(( $2 == "!!")||($2 == "*"))) print $1}' /etc/shadow
```

Comment: You are totally right, the base was chosed incorrectly. 1000 is a stupid "magic number", my fault.. but then.. so is 500?! Or, is it not?

Comment: This is not needed, your linked document states the operators in order of *increasing* precedence so `&&` does have a lower precedence than `>=` and `<`.

Comment: for redhat it is 500. Looks like no service used after 499. But that is actually only for RHEL. You can add something like "grep /home" or "grep /bin/bash" depend of your system settings. Also you can got only users with password - see above.

Comment: I believe Debian-based systems start at 1000.

Answer (score 2):

Extract the minimum and maximum user IDs from `/etc/login.defs` and then select the users with IDs between these margins from `/etc/passwd`:

```
UID_MIN=$(awk '/^UID_MIN/ {print $2}' /etc/login.defs)
UID_MAX=$(awk '/^UID_MAX/ {print $2}' /etc/login.defs)

awk -F: -v min=$UID_MIN -v max=$UID_MAX '$3 >= min && $3 <= max{print $1}' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: On a side note, the `if` is superfluous...just do `'$3 >= min && $3 <= max{print $1}'`.

Comment: This will miss many, in some cases, nearly all users at sites using LDAP, NIS, and other user mechanisms that include databases stored outside of the /etc/passwd file.

Comment: @AlexNorth-Keys True. However, I was under the impression that he was looking for local users.

Comment: Some crazy folks use LDAP for local users too ;-)  He didn't specify whether only the /etc/passwd file was to be used as the  source.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach that only spawns one external program, `getent` (suggested by @AnsgarWiechers) so that both local and networked passwd databases will be used.  This one reduces the number of forks to just one for `getent` itself.  Its portability is limited somewhat by requiring bash4, however.

```
get_users ()
{ 
    local IFS=$' \t#'
    while read var val ; do
        case "$var" in 
            UID_MIN) min="$val" ;;
            UID_MAX) max="$val" ;;
        esac
    done < /etc/login.defs
    declare -A users
    local IFS=:
    while read user pass uid gid gecos home shell; do
        if (( min <= uid && uid <= max )) && [[ ! $shell =~ '/(nologin|false)$' ]]; then
            users[$user]=1
        fi
    done < <(getent passwd 2>/dev/null)
    echo ${!users[@]}
}
```

Comment: +1. You should mention though that this requires `bash4`, so is not a very portable solution.

Answer (score 1):

So you're just trying to get a list of all users from /etc/passwd? If so, I believe this would be an easier solution:

```
cut -d":" -f1 /etc/passwd
```

**Edit:**

In case you only want a list of user-defined users (not the system users), you can use one of these:

```
grep -E ":[0-9]{4,6}:[0-9]{4,6}:" /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f1
```

^ This assumes your system uses 1000 and up for UID and GID for user-defined users

```
grep /home /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f1
```

^ This assumes every user-defined user has a home directory.

Other solutions depend on more detailed criteria and your system settings.

Comment: Cool ideas in your edit. I learned something. Still looks like a hack though, doesn't it?

Comment: @Robottinosino: Nope, that's just regular shell scripting :)

Comment: Many sites have user home directories scattered across filesystems and often even across the network on different hosts - and not all of them create a /home meta directory for them.  /net/server1/fs/d3/users/tom for example.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simplification of @StephenOstermiller's answer which gets it done with only two processes.  I think it is easier to read, too (provided you are familiar with the awk `NR==FNR` idiom).

```
getent passwd |
awk 'NR==FNR { if ($1 ~ /^UID_(MIN|MAX)$/) m[$1] = $2; next }
{ split ($0, a, /:/);
  if (a[3] >= m["UID_MIN"] && a[3] <= m["UID_MAX"] && a[7] !~ /(false|nologin)$/)
    print a[1] }' /etc/login.defs -
```

The different split patterns in the two inputs is a bit of a wart; maybe you could fix that more elegantly somehow.