# Bash: Backup all users from /home/ and place it to username.tar.gz

Tags: bash, backup

I want backup all users from /home/ and create username.tar.gz for each user. How to get users list from /home/ for Bash?

Comment: @AvinashRaj: If mirrol uses LDAP, this won't work.

Comment: googled it?.........

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shell script to get list of defined users on Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633614/shell-script-to-get-list-of-defined-users-on-linux)

Answer (score 1):

```
for each in `ls -d /home/*`
do
  # check whether the directory is present in /etc/passwd
  if grep -q $each /etc/passwd
  then
    tar -czf ${each}.tar.gz ${each}
  fi
done
```

This code takes each entries in `/home` directory and checks whether that is present in `/etc/passwd` file. This check is made to prevent other files and directories apart from user home directories from getting tar-ed.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=: read  user _ uid gid _ home _ ; do
    [[ $home = /home/* && -d $home ]] || continue
    echo "User $user ($uid:$gid) has a home directory: $home"
done < /etc/passwd
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
USERS = `ls /home | xargs -r`
for user in  $USERS; do
    tar -czf /home/$user.tar.gz /home/$user
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for file in /home*
do
tar -cvzf $file.tar.gz $file
done
```

The `for` loop can expand wildcard character `*` to list all the files in `pwd` by default. Since here it is given as `/home/*` it expands all the files and folders within the `/home/` direcotry. Thus for each iteration, the `file` will have different files in `/home/`

Comment: maybe add some explanations on top of the script!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some folders under /home do not belong to a user or maybe the user have home dir not named with its username.

So I think you'd better use `cat /etc/passwd | grep "/home" | awk -F: '{print $1}'` to get the users who have home dir in /home, and use `cat /etc/passwd | grep "/home" | awk -F: '{print $6}'` to get the users' home dir.